# Java: Is there any method in JTextPane that does the same thing as append() in JTextArea?

Tags: swing, netbeans-6.9, jtextfield, jtextarea, jtextpane

The program lets the user type in a command in a textfield then whatever they typed will show in the text area. If it is keywords such as yes it will turn green, however I cannot set just one line of text green in a text area so I need to use a text pane.

The problem is that if I use a text pane I can't use the append method anymore.

```
private final static String newline = "\n";
private void enterPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      
    int key = evt.getKeyCode();
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
    {
       String textfieldEnterdValue = textfield1.getText().toString();
       this.TextArea1.append("> "+tb1EnterdValue+newline);
       this.tb1.setText("");
       if((tb1EnterdValue.equals("yes")) )
        {
            TextArea1.setForeground(Color.green);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[JTextPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html) uses [Document](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html) as a model. This is necessary to support the use of multiple colors and fonts.
So, to append to a JTextPane, you need to modify the Document.
The following methods are available :

[insertString(int pos, String value, AttributeSet att)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html#insertString%28int,%20java.lang.String,%20javax.swing.text.AttributeSet%29)
[remove(int pos, int length)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html#remove%28int,%20int%29)

For example, this will append `value` to the end of the document.

```
Document d = textPane.getDocument();
d.insertString(d.getLength(), value, null);
```

Additionally, you may want to call [scrollRectToVisible(Rectangle)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#scrollRectToVisible%28java.awt.Rectangle%29) with the result of [modelToView(int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#modelToView%28int%29) to ensure the newly added line is on screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to do that directly on the underlying document.

Something like this:

```
String value = textfield1.getText(); // no need for toString() here!
textPane.getDocument().insertString(textPane.getCaretPosition(), value, null);
```